# tikz: placing nodes relative to the bounding box coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I have a `tikzpicture`,in this case a blue rectangle, that will produce a `bounding box`, here visualized by the green background. I would now like to place a `node` in the top left corner of the `bounding box`. In this case, since I know the `absolute coordinates` it is easy to do, but that is not always the case, especially when using external graphics or drawing three dimensional objects in rotated coordinate systems. It would therefore be handy, to be able to place the `nodes` relative to the `bounding box`. In the `axis` environment, nodes can be placed in relative coordinates using `rel axis cs`. In this case the code would be `\node at (rel axis cs:0,1) [anchor=north west] {node content}`. Since in my example, there is no pre-defined `axis`,this is not possible here. Is there something similar for a plain `tikzpicture`?

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tight background,background rectangle/.style=
 {fill=green},show background rectangle] \path[draw=black,fill=blue]
 (0,-1) -- (-1,0) -- (1,2) -- (2,1) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `current bounding box.north west`  with proper `anchor`. Since the `bounding box` will vary when we add something, it will be better to fix it by adding `use as bounding box` (thanks to zeroth). Then we are let loose to use all options like `positioning` library etc. A little example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tight background,background rectangle/.style= {fill=green},show background rectangle, ] 
\path[draw=black,fill=blue,use as bounding box] (0,-1) -- (-1,0) -- (1,2) -- (2,1) -- cycle;    %%% note the use as bounding box here
\node [draw,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at (current bounding box.north west)(me) {me};
\node [draw,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west,below=.7cm of me]  {me};
\node [draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south] at ($(current bounding box.south east)+(-.5,.5)$) {you};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Relative positioning can be done by making use of the available anchors of the bounding box. A simple demonstration will be:

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tight background,background rectangle/.style= {fill=green},show background rectangle, ] 
\path[draw=black,fill=blue,use as bounding box] (0,-1) -- (-1,0) -- (1,2) -- (2,1) -- cycle;    %%% note the use as bounding box here
\node [draw,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at (current bounding box.north west)(me) {me};
\node [draw,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,anchor=west] at ($(current bounding box.north west)!.37!(current bounding box.south west)$) {me};  %% 37% from north west
\node [draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,anchor=center] at ($(current bounding box.south)!.5!(current bounding box.east)$) {you};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, please note the comment by zeroth below to disable the updating of bounding box.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem for my example. But, just out of interest, let's assume I would like to have the node at 63% height, is that possible, too?

Comment: the only problem with this approach is that the bounding box is not a fixed dimension size when creating the figure. Doing the 'me' node twice will not put it the same place. One could fix the bounding box with `use as bounding box` on a specific path.

Comment: This indeed is a problem. Using `current bounding box.north west` and after that `current bounding box.south west` will not place the nodes beneath each other.

Comment: @HarishKumar But then, unfortunately, we are back to the beginning of the question. If I have coordinates to specify a path as the bounding box, then I could use the same coordinates to place the nodes. I would not need to go the extra way using the bounding box.

Comment: @HarishKumar an easy fix is to make pgf __not__ update the bounding box via this: `\makeatletter
\let\disablebbupdate\pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse
\let\enablebbupdate\pgf@relevantforpicturesizetrue
\makeatother` and insert `\disablebbupdate` right before the 'me' node.

Comment: Ok, so as for placing a `node` in the upper left corner of the `bounding box` without expanding it, the problem is solved. The only question, that remains is about more arbitrary positions of the `node`. In your example you use absolute values to shift the `node`s. When the size of the rectangle is changed, so will the positions of the nodes relative to the rectangle.

Comment: @Janek I made an edit for relative positioning. But the options are some what limited here.

Comment: I like zeroth's most recent suggestion (particularly if made into an environment rather than a pair of commands), since it provides a way to re-enable updating of the bounding box. This is probably not relevant for this particular question, but could well be relevant in other situations.

Comment: You can use `overlay` option or put content inside `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment to avoid bounding box being updated.

Comment: @percusse yes, that was the environment, there had to be an environment for this! :)

Comment: Nice, all questions answered! Thank you all.